# Does collar restrict to a closed neighbourhood?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

Suppose $X$ is a (smooth) manifold with boundary and $f: [0,\infty)\times \partial X \rightarrow X$ is an open embedding such that $f(0,x) = x (\forall x \in \partial X) $ i.e., a collar.
Is $f([0,1] \times \partial X)$ closed in $X$ ?

It seems to be true but I have some problems: Suppose $f(t_n,x_n) \to y\in X$, where $t_n \in [0,1]$ and $x_n \in \partial X$. I try to show that $y = f(t,x)$ for some $t\in [0,1]$ and $x\in \partial X$. But I don't know how to deal with the case where $y \in X-Im(f)$. Thank you.

Comment: You have to assume more than you did in order to get closed image. One usually assumes priperness of the map $\partial M\times [0,1]$. This ensures that the image is closed.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: I was trying to construct a counter-example if you don't assume the mapping is proper. Do you know of one?

Comment: @RobArthan: of course.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: can you share the counter-example with us, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example.

Let $X$ be the upper half-plane $\{(x,y): y\ge 0\}$. Consider the map
$$
f: (x,t) \mapsto ((1-t)x + t(e^x+1), t), \quad 0\le t\le 1, x\in {\mathbb R}. 
$$
This map restricts to the identity map when $t=0$ and sends ${\mathbb R}\times [0,1]$ onto
$$
U={\mathbb R}\times [0,1) \cup (0,\infty)\times \{1\}\subset X,
$$
which is the strip $0\le y\le 1$ with a ray removed from the top. Hence, $U$ is not closed. I am leaving it to you to check that
$$
f: {\mathbb R}\times [0,1]\to U$$
is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Thanks. In my settings, maybe I should modify $f$ by defining $f(x,t) = ((1-t)^2x+t^2e^x ,t)$.

Comment: @Skyskie: Yes, if you want to extend $f$ further (to an embedding).